justify text in react native, but last line be rtl
I've some Arabic text in react native, and I want to make it justify (fill the width from both sides), but the last line be right aligned.
When I set textAlign: "justify" style for <Text>, the text is justified properly, except last line. Last line will be in left of the row.
I also tried to use textAlignLast: "right", but it doesn't work in react native.
Any solution?

There is one thing called I18nManager available in react-native you can use that to change the whole layout to RTL. It will change the whole layout not just the text. And you can use all other properties of react-native as well.
import RNRestart from "react-native-restart";
...
import {I18nManager} from "react-native";

export const languageRestart = async () => {
    //changing language based on what was chosen
    if (//selected language is LTR) {
           if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
                    await I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
               }
    } else {
           if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
                 await I18nManager.forceRTL(true); // will change to RTL
               }
    }
    RNRestart.Restart();
};


I don't nee to switch whole app direction. app is already designed RTL using flex.
